# UWP BLE Advertising read data

Tags: c#, ios, bluetooth, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

I send data (short string) in BLE Advertising with an iPhone and I want to read this string from a Windows device.

So I'm trying the sample project "BluetoothAdvertisement" from : https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothAdvertisement

I see that i receive packages, I can read the localname etc... in the callBack:

```
 private async void OnAdvertisementReceived(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs eventArgs)
    { }
```

But how can I read the string ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know which ways you used to add data to an Advertisement, if you are using a company-specific advertisement.  I think you can get custom data section from `BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs`,and then query `eventArgs.Advertisement.ManufacturerData` to get `BluetoothLEManufacturerData`.

```
private async void OnAdvertisementReceived(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    var DataList = eventArgs.Advertisement.ManufacturerData;
    foreach (var temp in DataList)
    {
        var data = new byte[temp.Data.Length];
        using (var reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(temp.Data))
        {
            reader.ReadBytes(data);
        }
        var str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
    }
}
```